# Creating Cocos2dxGame for iOS using eclipse on Windows Machine

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am using windows machine and trying to make a game for iOS in cocos2dx. The editor I am using is Eclipse. Version of cocos2dx is latest.

I have followed many tutorials but not a single tutorial guides me how to code in eclipse for iOS using cocos2dx.

I have seen Classes folder which contains Appdelegate.h and cpp along with helloworld.h and cpp.

When I create a new android project using existing project, i am unable to find classes folder.

I need help on how to get started.

Thank you

Comment: iOS development is only (officially) supported on Mac OS X. You may be able to build, but you can't run the app neither on device nor on the non-existent iOS Simulator. There are ways to deploy from Windows but that's just something hackers do, it's not feasible for non-experts (myself included). There are also 3rd party services but you can't use them with cocos2d.

Comment: hmmm agree but how about coding for android with targetting a single resolution of iphone. if code is successfully running on android than i can keep my finger crossed and hope it will run fine on iphone too. your thoughts?

Comment: cocos2d-x has its own way to handle multiple resolution. for more info you can check http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Multi_resolution_support LearnCocos2D is right, you can officially only build iOS app using a Mac OS X(android app can be built in OS X as well).

Comment: i understand how resolution is handled for iOS but how can those 4 different size images be used for different resoultions of android